# is there a way to check the size of an array in a function which is not predefined in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

hey guys i just realised that when we try and find the size of an array using a function that is user defined it returns a garbage value. for example check this code:

```
int s(int arr[]){
return sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
}
```

when we do this `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);` directly in the main function then it will give the correct answer, but when we use a different function it wont give an error but instead it gives some address.
how do i solve this problem?

ps: the reason for this qn is that i have a coding problem in a uni exam, and for that we have to write a userdefined function that would involve finding the length of an input array, but we arent allowed to change the main function.

ps2: this is an introduction to programming course, so i cant be using templates or structs to find the answ.

Comment: `int s(int arr[])` is just another way to write `int s(int* arr)`. `sizeof(arr)` is the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8), not the size of the data pointed to. No, there's no way to recover the size of the data from the pointer alone; the caller would need to pass it along. Or, consider using `std::vector`, it knows its own size.

Comment: yeah i would rather use a vector but the problem is that we cant edit the main function. we can only edit a user defined function, which takes in only an array (not a vector) and doesnt take the length of the array as an input.

Comment: I mean, the answer is to use std::array. However for your unique requirements, you could pass the size as a second parameter, or define it as a const global variable.

Comment: Well, there's a trick: `template <size_t N> int s(int (&arr)[N]) {...}`. This captures the array size in `N` (you don't need to use the `sizeof` trick, but that will work, too). I doubt that's what your course had in mind, but there you have it.

Comment: if your signature must be `int s(int arr[])` then there is no way to get the size except for a sentinel value, like how c-strings work.  Otherwise you need to change the function to have a parameter for the size.

Comment: In extreme cases you can also get disgusting: Store the size of the array in a global variable and write your function using that global variable. Thoroughly disgusting, doesn't scale, and a <expletive deleted> to debug if you try to force scale onto it. Never do it in real code.